# Laravel 403 error (production) when doing ajax POST request only in HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, https

I've been through the web for about 3 hours to find a solution to my issue but can not find out...

I've uploaded my laravel application on a shared host, so the file architecture looks like:

[image]

The .htaccess is the laravel default:

[image]

All my routes work fine when my website is hosted with HTTP (or in local) but when I switch it to HTTP**S** (applying from the OVH hosting panel) it breaks all my `POST` request (via ajax) to 403 error (Can't access... on this server).

Api route example: `https://mywebsite.com/api/v1/login`

If you have any suggestion, don't hesitate! Thanks.

Comment: I am not an expert in this, but take a look at HTTP:Authorization, that seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: It was not an htaccess issue, but thanks anyway @LajosArpad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of things, but I finally got the solution:

- In my web hosting (OVH) panel, there was a firewall on the host, I disactivated it.
- I regenerated the SSL certificate.
- I destroyed cookies and session.

I don't know which one exactly made the trick but it saved my day!